# Achieving low-frequency clocks in FPGA fabric when below what PLL can provide

Tags: fpga

I have a 100 MHz reference clock source coming in from the XTAL on the board (Xilinx). As a trivial example, I wish to build a 1Hz virtual clock to drive a real-world clock/timer.

Now, as I see it, the Clocking Wizard is incapable of producing a frequency that low using PLL primitives or even if it were capable, the jitter and inaccuracy would be atrocious.

So that leaves me with a couple of options:

- Use the Clocking Wizard to produce a clock which is ~an order of magnitude slower than the XTAL, then use a traditional counter divider to reach 1 Hz.
- Directly use a traditional counter divider to reach 1 Hz.

My reasoning is that the first solution would help improve efficiency by minimising switching power losses, but both solutions don't feel particularly efficient to me.

Is there a way that I can achieve a very slow clock which is also not burning up millions of cycles just to count?

Comment: Generally if you are intending to generate a 1Hz output, 100MHz would be a bad choice.  If that's all you have, how else are you going to do it but divide it down?

Comment: The cycles must be burnt, with either a counter you design or a counter in the PLL.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson to be fair, dedicated PLL silicon tends to be pretty power-efficient, but I doubt that a 24bit counter running at 2²⁴ Hz would eat much power...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson (and what happened to using maximum-length sequences from LFSR to reduce complexity compared to counters used for dividing clocks?)

Comment: The LFSR idea is quite nice, altough not exactly flexible, unless you have an algorithm to design such a register with a given length (maybe it exists). However at first glance I see a pigeon-hole problem… if you need to count up to 1000 (say) you need 10 bits (flops). To have an LFSR with such a length you need 1000 states, so they still eat 10 flops from the fabric. Also combinatorial logic in FPGA is free (it's made from LUTs), and in every architecture I've seen the flops are part of a slice with some LUTs in it so unless you're borrowing slices I don't see a useful gain

Comment: Also: most FPGA slice architectures have dedicated routes for making adders so a counter is probably the most optimizable thing ever. And, last but not least, using logic instead of a PLL you are not crossing a clock domain so no synchronizers are needed

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio hm, synchronizers wouldn't be needed for a clock divider, either way, since to low clock is synchronous to the high clock (we're the clock generator...). However, you're right, for "cute little decimation factors" like 1000, there's little to no advantage. However, you run into a problem if you run high decimation factors from high-rate clocks: say you want to go from \$2^N\$ Hz down to 1 Hz. Sure, a N-bit counter works, but you'll have to have a single-clock adder for with N-1 ripple bits, which is significantly more complex than a N-bit LFSR generating a MLS, which only

Comment: needs a mere 32 FFs and 4 XORs (!), no adders at all. That way, you only need a single LUT to do the feedback, whereas a 32 bit adder definitely needs multiple. Even your 1000-counter needs a 10 bit adder, which is even on a series 7 Xilinx FPGA 2 LUTs, plus 10 FFs.

Comment: Re: finding LFSRs... well, there's algebra and a lot known polynomials. Genrally, you build non-power-of-2 things by combining cheap&high-speed LFSRs with classical counters, should the ratio have even prime factors.

Comment: Folks, please don't use the question comments as a chat forum. If anyone wishes to formulate an answer, I'd appreciate it. To respond to the "how else are you going to do it" question, there is dedicated clocking H/W separate to main fabric which doesn't perform trivial counting as evidenced by other comments...

Comment: 22 registers with a few gates are enough to have a counter that can count 25 million cycles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use Clocking Wizard to generate timing pulses for external use, as SCL serial clocks for I2C or SPI protocol or whatever else. The Clocking Wizard application area is stated in a Vivado Design Suite document [Clocking Wizard v6.0 LogiCORE IP Product Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/clk_wiz/v6_0/pg065-clk-wiz.pdf), page 7:

> **Applications**
>
> - The creation of clock networks with the required frequency, phase, and duty cycle, with reduced jitter.
> - Electromagnetic interference reduction in electronic devices using the Spread Spectrum feature.

The creation of **clock networks** for use within your FPGA chip, and not of clock pulses/signals that may be used elsewhere.

Read also about clock networks, clock routing and other clocking features, what these do in your FPGA and why these are outright waste of resources to carry your "1Hz virtual clock" signals.

If you want to build "a 1Hz virtual clock" as an exercise in building resource-optimized variable length shift registers, follow instructions from a Vivado Design Suite document [RAM-Based Shift Register v12.0 LogiCORE IP Product Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/shift_ram/v12_0/pg122-c-shift-ram.pdf) or similar documents of your choice. The output of your "virtual clock" generating circuit goes to an output IO pin, and not to a clock region; you need not route this signal around within your FPGA.

If you are interested in how the design tools implement your VHDL/Verilog code, read about slice registers/slice LUTs/distributed RAM.

Do not worry about "burning up millions of cycles just to count": FPGA is made to run millions and even more of cycles; IP cores take care of optimizing power and resource costs to help FPGA do a useful job. Just notice that for tasks similar to your hypothetical task, the hardware solutions sort of RTC chips with 32.768KHz crystals are recommended.

Comment: Great, thanks. Yes I am aware of the 32.768kHz crystal usage in timing applications. As you pointed out, this was hypothetical.

Comment: "Do not use Clocking Wizard to generate timing pulses for external use, as SCL serial clocks for I2C or SPI protocol or whatever else" -- Adding some context. They can't be directly used outside. However, the clock generated by PLL/MMCM can be forwarded to the outside of FPGA using ODDR. I have successfully used it as SPI Clock in past in a source-synchronous interface.

Comment: @MituRaj You're right. I've somewhat over-emphasized the first application item to help the OP grasp the very context that you correctly indicate in your comment. Surely, a designer can and should use pll/mmcm generated clocks outside the chip, for example, to provide readily available EMI reduction in generated clock waveforms.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use a standard behavioral counter.  Depending on the input speed, and the device, I might choose to use a small 2^n pre-divider for the higher frequency part (i.e., divide by 4 to get to 25MHz in your example).  Then, just divide by 25M to get to your 1Hz.  I don't know if you can save power by using the PLL, but probably not, and that will only save you a few FFs in your counter.  I routinely use counters like this (usually just to implement a heartbeat LED, which is nice in the lab).